# How to do perform "contains" in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

Cell A contains users email address and B contains domain. (ex: email as a@gmail.com, domain is gmail. email as  b@yahoo.com, domain is yahoo etc).

I want to find out domain and the email address matching or not.  I am not quite sure how to perform this in excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Search and Isnumber:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using find and search :

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("@",A1)+1=SEARCH(B1,A1),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the `FIND` function is case sensitive so it will not find "gmail" if the email is listed as "email@Gmail.com".  The `Search` function is not case sensitive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for info, but in this case i am using find to find the position of "@".